# My password does not work

Tags: login, password, reset

I have installed VirtualBox and Xubuntu today, and have set a password and took a photo of it while on the "unattended guest OS install set up".

After then completing all the steps that were described on the Odin Project website, I finally got to the login part, only to find out that the same exact password I took a picture of was classified as incorrect.

How did this happen? Am I missing something, since the computer is always right?

I tried resetting my password, by restarting and then pressing Shift + Esc and got to the point of "give root password for maintenance". This now confuses me even more as I don’t know my password in the first place. I have read and seen that I am supposed to type in linux as my maintenance password, however this was also unsuccessful. Do you think I should restart the whole OS, as in delete it and install again?

Comment: Check the keyboard caps-lock and num-lock keys.  On some keyboards, the numlock will change some letters to numbers (and passwords don't echo, so you don't realize you're typing numbers). Ubuntu has no root password, you use the password for the user with sudo privs.

Comment: In addition to @ubfan1's comment, it's possible that, at login, your keyboard is set to a different locale than when you did the installation.  So, punctuation marks are at different locations, etc.  You should also check for that.

Comment: Hello, apologies for the late response, thank you for the answers. I just reinstalled the entire thing and chose an easy to remember password for now